# String or integer query in mongoDB for a single field

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In MongoDB, there is field named vehId. It contains value in string as well in integer. like

```
{
"vehId" : "12"
}

or

{
"vehId" : 12
}

or

{
"vehId" : ""
}
```

If I do query as vehId as integer it return only vehId having value in Integer as for string it return only string. But I need a single query for both string and integer . Like

```
collection.find({"vehId" : <value> })
```

I need a single query that return all value. If I pass vehId as integer it also return values having vehId in string and vice-versa

Comment: So just supply both the integer and string values as an argument to `$in`.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I am getting only one value, it may be string or integer

Comment: Blakes is asking to run query like collection.find({"vehId" : { $in: [12, "12"}})

Comment: Anyway I got the idea how to do it. Thanks @BlakesSeven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So If you have situation like above, you can get your results easily with:

```
collection.find({"vehId" : { $in: [intval($vehId), $vehId}})
```

Comment: I strongly don't recommend this approach, unless you're sure that `$vehId` is always going to contain only numeric value. For example, if `$vehId` = '123abc', then your script will match 123 AND '123abc' !

Comment: In db $vehId is always integer and its auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.find({ $or: [{"vehId":value}, {"vehId": intval(value)}})
```